# Is there a "bartender"-like app for Ubuntu?

Tags: indicator

There is an app for OSX called "Bartender" that lets you hide multiple app indicators behind a single icon. I've tried looking for an Ubuntu/*nix equivalent to no avail. Does any one have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu pioneered "indicators" instead of "system tray icons" as they were before in order to solve this problem. There are now a limited number of indicators that are based on function, and each indicator can represent multiple applications.

Examples: the sound indicator controls your system volume and also your music player; the messaging indicator interfaces with instant messaging, email and microblogging.

More information at: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/ApplicationIndicators

However, this is really for developers. I'm not aware of any mechanism that allows users to collapse multiple system tray icons without getting a developer to alter the program. Perhaps someone else has an answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

KDE environment in kubuntu have plasma widgets having similar feature. You can define group on desktop icons.